# Do you think this p=np workaround worth to try?

Tags: optimization

I need consultancy for a possible **p=np** workaround.
First of all sorry for my English because it is going to be long question:) To better understand the architecture which I design maybe you will need to have experience with matrix operations and a bit object oriented programming. I wanted to tag this question also to computer science but I couldn’t figure out how. Maybe it is not perfect idea but I think it is worth to ask:)

**Problem Description:**
I have been thinking about possibilities for solving ***p=np*** problem.  If you would like to read more about it here is the Wikipedia link: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).  A small example stated here (from wiki):

> Consider the subset sum problem, an example of a problem that is easy to verify, but whose answer may be difficult to compute. Given a set of integers, does some nonempty subset of them sum to 0? For instance, does a subset of the set {−2, −3, 15, 14, 7, −10} add up to 0? The answer "yes, because the subset {−2, −3, −10, 15} adds up to zero" can be quickly verified with three additions. There is no known algorithm to find such a subset in polynomial time (there is one, however, in exponential time, which consists of 2n-n-1 tries), but such an algorithm exists if P = NP; hence this problem is in NP (quickly checkable) but not necessarily in P (quickly solvable).

**What is the idea:**
Every day we do the same calculations in multiple PC`s around the world, so the solution I am thinking (in theory) a central database for those calculations to provide result. Long story in short, **i.e.** when you multiply large matrixes then your application will do a API call from a global database instead of using local resources.

**How does it work:**
Lets assume you develop your project in Java. So you will include IIT (Information Is There) Matrix library into your project. Then (i.e.) you will create a new 2D Matrix object instance as below:

```
IITMatrix matrix = new IITMatrix(2);
```

And you will append new values as below:

```
matrix.add(1,0.599);
```

First parameter is the dimension and the second one is the actual value. When you append a value to your matrix object, then the matrix automatically will generate/update a hash using [LZ4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) at background (its called *instance variable* for java guys:)). When you need to do an operation with another matrix you will call i.e.:

```
matrix.multiply(myAnotherMatrix);
```

Now we are using API future instead of your local resources. Multiply method automatically will call below url :

```
http://www.mycentraldb.org/iit/multiply/100/300?a=4jh3k5g4hj3g5443kh5g43&b=fjsdfhjsdljsdljsdljsdljsdlkdf
```

Let`s say **100** is the rows and **300** is our columns. **A** parameter is the generated hash of first matrix and **B** parameter generated hash of second matrix. Then backend *load balancer* will find the matching server (*key&value noSQL server*) for 100x300 and it will query **4jh3k5g4hj3g5443kh5g43: fjsdfhjsdljsdljsdljsdljsdlkdf** for the value. When server will return another Hash as response then your matrix object will parse it and wraps another matrix object. i.e. something like that:

```
IITMatrix result = matrix.multiply(myAnotherMatrix);
```

**Performance advantage:**
When you start your project IIT library, application will establish a socket connection until you close application, so each single query will be done in milliseconds without lookup.

**How the data generated:**
   Caching all the numbers is not possible but the exceptional amount of dimensions would be useful. Maybe first target can be combinations of normalized values between -1 and 1 with 6 decimal points (Combination of 2000000). And the server will keep generating hashes by increasing values and when a dimension is done it will create another DB dump for the new one. Using a GPU farm would beneficial. Even a P2P connection or parallel computing MPI network should allow community to share/generate more resources. Also operations will grow i.e. mod, log etc operations will be added into API as well.

**So my question is:**
 Can this solution fit your daily needs? How it would be better? Should I start? :) I am asking in advance because I don’t want to remove data after days of generation. I have few GPUs to give a shot:)

Comment: One word: *latency*.

Comment: I am not mentioning here about single server, multiple servers and a load balancer. Even also a p2p network is possible (like torrent). Of course in theory:)

Comment: Can you trim the question of unnecessary detail? The question of whether precomputing numerical calculations makes practical sense is to a great extent independent of how it's implemented, and also has absolutely no bearing on P=NP, which is really irrelevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is whether pre-computing results allows you to come up with an algorithm that shows that even NP problems can be solved in P time, then the answer is no. This is so because statements such as "problem A is in P/NP" are stated *asymptotically* as the size of the problem gets larger and larger. But you won't be able to provide your database for larger and larger problems: you will run out of resources to store, let alone compute, the answers for problems beyond a certain size.

So no, this is no way to prove that P=NP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time, it turns out the idea more applicable to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization as a central database but has no relation with the p=np, but still I would like to try some application areas which will lead me to study&learn more:)